# Should I have both active directory and public tertiary dns configured for my clients

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory

As often happens I have a practice I've followed for a long time but can no longer find evidence to support it. Has it ever been the case that Windows clients round robined requests between the DNS servers configured in TCP/IP properties? From what I can find now it appears that Windows actually does fail over from primary the secondary (based on a specific process) but I don't think that was always the case.

Regardless, I can find no documentation to support my belief that in an Active Directory environment all clients should only be configured to use the Active Directory DNS server(s) and not also be configured to use some external DNS server.

Anyone care to share link to evidence to support my stance?

Answer (score 1):

Clients in a AD Domain should have two or three of their site's AD DNS servers configured. They should never have anything else configured. Windows should always failover from a non-responsive primary to secondaries and so on. The DNS servers should be configured to do independent recursive resolution, or to forward (your choice, however you want them to work).

As according to [Best practicies for DNS clients](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825036)

> Configure the primary and secondary DNS client settings to point to local primary and secondary DNS servers (if local DNS servers are available) that host the DNS zone for the computer's Active Directory domain.
>
> If there are no local DNS servers available, point to a DNS server for that computer's Active Directory domain that can be reached through a reliable WAN link (Up-time and bandwidth determine reliability.)
>
> Do not configure the client DNS settings to point to your ISP's DNS servers. If you do so, you may experience issues when you try to join the Windows 2000-based or Windows Server 2003-based server to the domain, or when you try to log on to the domain from that computer. Instead, the internal DNS server should forward to the ISP's DNS servers to resolve external names.

<sub>Note: this specific article is talking about Server 2000 and 2003; but nothing has changed since then.</sub>

Comment: But all of those recommendations are specific to the Active Directory servers. It does not speak to the actual workstations themselves.

Comment: Um, no... the part I quoted is specifically for not AD servers. And it really wouldn't make sense for an AD server to have to reach itself over a reliable WAN link.